# Images worked locally but don't work when pushed to firebase hosting?

Tags: html

I'm having trouble with my images when I deploy my site to firebase hosting, they are not appearing (they do work locally though). I have tried different paths but can't seem to see the images no matter which way I go about it. My css works fine.

Please help.

[image]

```html
<div class="offering">
        <div class="headings">
            <h2>Move with us</h2>
            <p>This platform is for you to start, inspire, help and motivate your journey no matter where you are within yourself along the way.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="allround-container">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="public/images/sule-makaroglu-PnUYkTFkOD0-unsplash.jpg" class="offeringimg" alt="strength and conditioning">
                <div class="overlay">    
                    <div class="title">Strength & Condtioning</div>
                    <p class="imgDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consloribu, blanditiis delectus fuga cum venm dolor sit amet consloribu, blanditiis delectus fuga cum veniam nisi fugiat? Vero.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="./public/images/inspired-horizons-digital-marketing-kufLAiPoIlI-unsplash.jpg" class="offeringimg"  alt="sport specific training">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="title">Sport Specifics</div>
                    <p class="imgDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consloribu, blanditiis delectus fuga cum venm dolor sit amet consloribu, blanditiis delectus fuga cum veniam nisi fugiat? Vero.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="/images/inspired-horizons-digital-marketing-I749-lKHHJ4-unsplash.jpg" class="offeringimg"  alt="recreational activities">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="title">Recreational Activities</div>
                    <p class="imgDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consloribu, blanditiis delectus fuga cum venm dolor sit amet consloribu, blanditiis delectus fuga cum veniam nisi fugiat? Vero.</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. The path had to be `/images/imagefile`